# Overflow error when using large size pointer array in Intel fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, stack-overflow, subroutine, intel-fortran

how can I avoid getting an overflow error when using a big size pointer array 
My code is simply creating a subroutine to read a file and get data and store it in two arrays (the dimension of the array is to be declared inside the function)

the dimension of the two arrays is declared inside the subroutine, and to allocate them and get them out of the subroutine without the pointer, it gives the error

```
    ARRAY1 is a dummy argument and so cannot be ALLOCATABLE
```

Here is the code and the error is in the line of the subroutine call

```
! declaration Main code
CHARACTER*200 :: configfile = "config.txt"
INTEGER*4, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: add_array(:,:), route_array(:,:)

call ReadConfigfile(configfile, array1, array2)
```

and the subroutine is

```
SUBROUTINE ReadConfigfile(fname, array1, array2)
integer :: dim1, dim2
CHARACTER*200 :: fname
INTEGER*4, POINTER :: array1(:,:), array2(:,:)

some statements to get the dimension from the file 

allocate(array2(dim1,5), array2(dim2,5))

some statements to get store the numbers from the file into array1 & array2

END SUBROUTINE ReadConfigfile
```

and the error I get is

```
Integer overflow at address 004019933 in file flowaccumulation.95 at line 161
```

Comment: Which line is line 161? I don't the statement `allocate(array2(dim1,5), array2(dim2,5))` is intended but probably `allocate(array1(dim1,5), array2(dim2,5))`. What is the value of `dim1` and of `dim2`? Also what are `array1` and `array2` in the main code?

Comment: Best guess: the size of one of your arrays is greater than `2^31-1` elements.  For anything like an answer post a [mcve] which exhibits the fault.  And why are you mixing pointers and allocatable arrays like that ?

Comment: In fact why are you using pointers at all?

Comment: line 161 is the line where the subroutine is called " call ReadConfigfile(configfile, array1, array2) "

Comment: the value of dim1 and dim3 is going to be defined based on the data on the file, but mostly it is bery high number

Comment: Please create a MWE.

Comment: You absolutely want to use ALLOCATABLE rather than POINTER in the subroutine, and that you don't get compile errors suggests to me that there's no explicit interface visible to the caller. This may be part of your problem. I am also puzzled at the wording of the error message, as that doesn't look like any message Intel Fortran puts out.

Comment: *but mostly it is bery high number*. Be specific.  Some people on SO think that `10^3` is a very high number, some think that `10^9` is still rather middling, and that very high only begins at about `2*10^9`.  Or even higher.  Be specific.